# Installing glusterfs client on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, glusterfs

I created glusterfs instances using Ubuntu TLS AMI. I want my existing instances (Amazon Linux AMI) connect to glusterfs servers.

There is no Amazon Linux folder at the glusterfs's download page: 
http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.3/3.3.1/

```
[DIR] CentOS/ 24-Oct-2012 13:27 - 
[DIR] Debian/ 30-Jan-2013 21:13 - 
[DIR] EPEL.repo/ 24-Oct-2012 13:27 - 
[DIR] Fedora/ 16-Oct-2012 15:25 - 
[DIR] Hadoop/ 25-Oct-2012 15:28 - 
[DIR] NetBSD/ 18-Oct-2012 11:24 - 
[DIR] RHEL/ 24-Oct-2012 13:27 - 
[DIR] UFO/ 07-Dec-2012 17:44 - 
[TXT] Ubuntu.README 22-Oct-2012 16:48 274 
[DIR] Ubuntu/ 17-Oct-2012 13:36 - 
[ ] glusterfs-3.3.1.tar.gz 15-Oct-2012 16:48 2.5M
```

How could I install glusterfs client to Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux is RPM based LInux you can download

http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.3/3.3.1/glusterfs-3.3.1.tar.gz

and compile GLUSTERFS

Comment: It give lots of error when I try make command.

Comment: shoud I use fedora or redhat package?

Comment: Yes that will also do ,give it a try but make sure you test enough before putting it in Production environment..

Comment: so you would compile it rather than using other rpm packages?

Comment: Every gluster instance I have I compiled on to CentOS 5->6.3, no problems at all, just make sure you install all the dependencies first.

Comment: Also from the sounds of it, you just need to use the Ubuntu package, Gluster will be running on an Ubuntu server right?